# Replacement for deprecated code: CGContextShowText

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I'm trying to upgrade my code to iOS 10 and I'm having trouble finding a replacement for some deprecated code. Usually Xcode 8 shows a replacement, but in the following case none was given.  My old code is:

```
CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial-BoldMT", fontSize, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetTextPosition(context, x, y);
CGContextShowText(context, [text UTF8String], text.length);
```

When I run this code it works o.k.  I then tried the following:

```
  // CGContextSetTextPosition(context, x, Y);
  // CGContextShowText(context, [text UTF8String], text.length);

  context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
  [text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(x, Y)
      withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:12]}];
  UIGraphicsPopContext();
```

The Xcode iPhone simulator runs without error messages, but the text does not appear.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Charles

Comment: 1. Is the x and y value appropriate? 2. Is `text` `non-nil`? 3. Are you sure that the `UIFont` is `non-nil`? 4. Try adding a color to the attributes when you draw the text.

Comment: Yes, the arguments are valid. I added: NSLog(@"text: %@, x: %.2f, Y: %.2f", text, x, Y); and got: text: NYSE TRIN 1.01 15:22:36, x: 83.00, Y: 277.75.  Also, UIFont of "Arial-BoldMT" worked with the old code.  The color is "white" and it shows over a blue background in the old code.

Comment: The color is not white since you do not set the color in the attributes along with the font.

Comment: And you have not actually verified that the `UIFont` isn't `nil`. Don't make assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it was the font color. Here is the replacement code that worked:

```
// CGContextSetTextPosition(context, x, Y);
// CGContextShowText(context, [text UTF8String], text.length);

context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
[text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(x, Y)
    withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:12], 
                                          NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];
UIGraphicsPopContext();
NSLog(@"text: %@, x: %.2f, Y: %.2f", text, x, Y);
```